# Set the Top of the Option Element as a Default Value

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

Let's say I have a state variable called `response` which contains a dynamic API response and its value is used as dropdown options in option tags. What I am trying to do is to set the top of the option value to another state variable called `selectedOption` as a default value. Afterwards, I am going to use it for making another API call. Here is the snippet I am talking about.

```
// response = useState([]) <- contains an api response
// selectedOption = useState('') 
// response -> recordset = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Mary'}, {name 'Michael'}] *These objects vary depending on an api call. 



<select onChange={(e) => setselectedOption(e.target.value)>
  {response?.recordset?.map((obj, key) => {
    return <option key={key} value={obj.name}>{obj.name}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

The above case, John is displayed at the top in the dropdown. However, `selectedOption` is null. Once I open the dropdown and click any option, then `selectedOption` will be updated with the selected value. Is there any way that I can set John to `selectedOption` without opening the dropdown and clicking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're iterating over the array `response.recordset` in your `<option/>` map, just use the first item in your initial state

```
const [response] = useState([]); // <- contains an api response
//response -> recordset = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Mary'}, {name 'Michael'}] // *These objects vary depending on an api call.
const [selectedOption] = useState( response.recordset[0] );
                           // This bit here --^

<select onChange={(e) => setselectedOption(e.target.value)>
  {response?.recordset?.map((obj, key) => {
    return <option key={key} value={obj.name}>{obj.name}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

And if you can't do that because your `useEffect` is async, just set the `selectedOption` as soon as you get the API responds and I would include an empty option.

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]); // <- contains an api response
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  // your fetch
  // response -> recordset = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Mary'}, {name 'Michael'}] *These objects vary depending on an api call. 
  setResponse(response);
  setSelectedOption(response.recordset[0]);
},[])


<select onChange={(e) => setselectedOption(e.target.value)>
  <option value="">Please select something below</option>
  {response?.recordset?.map((obj, key) => {
    return <option key={key} value={obj.name}>{obj.name}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second solution you provided works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If `response` is an array, you can access your object within each iteration, meaning, you can just do `resopnse.map()` instead of `response.recordset.map`

You also need to use `setSelectedOption` to update your state variable. It's a custom named function that `useState` provides.

As for selecting the first element, add the `selected` attribute to the first option.

```
[response, setResponse] = useState([])
[selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('') 

<select onChange={(e) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)>
  {response.map((obj, key) => {
    return <option key={key} value={obj.name} selected={key === 0}>{obj.name}</option>
  })}
</select>
```